# Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead

Tags: xml, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I have a website for which I'm trying to submit a sitemap to the google search-console. When I do, I get the error:

> Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.

My sitemap is in XML, so I don't understand what is wrong with it? This is the XML I'm submitting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

   <url>
     <loc>https://arter.dk/taxa/taxon/details/926eddf8-f785-ea11-aa77-501ac539d1ea</loc>
     <lastmod>2022-06-17T13:11:30+00:00</lastmod>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

It's being hosted here, and this is the link submitted: https://udv.arter.dk/sitemap.xml

What is wrong with my sitemap?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your sitemap.  `xmllint` reports that it is valid.  It is being served with a header of `content-type: application/xml` which is valid and doesn't indicate that it would be HTML.

My guess is that GSC hasn't fetched the sitemap recently and is seeing an old error.  You should either wait two weeks and try again or try inspecting your sitemap URL with a live test.

Comment: Ok, thanks for commenting, but it seems it has read the latest sitemap, at least today, but it still gives the same error.